# can't assign object value to object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, angular-redux

I am trying to assing an object to another object with the same type.

So, I have this object 'Language'

```
export class Language {
  languageDescription: string;
  languageCode: string;
  isDefault: boolean;
}
```

And I declared two objects `selectedLanguage` and `childSelectedLanguage` with the *Language* type :

```
@State<LanguageSelectorStateModel>({
  name: 'languageSelector',
  defaults: {
    languages: [],
    selectedLanguage: null,
    childSelectedLanguage: null
  }
})*
```

After the selectedLanguage is populated( no more null),

```
  @Action(UpdateSelectedLanguage)
  @ImmutableContext()
  updateSelectedLanguage({ getState, patchState }: StateContext<LanguageSelectorStateModel>, { languageCode }: UpdateSelectedLanguage) {
    const state = getState();
    const selectedLanguage = state.languages.find(language => language.languageCode === languageCode);
    state.selectedLanguage = selectedLanguage;
    patchState(state);
  }
```

I tried to assign the same content of this value : to childSelectedLanguage.

`childSelectedLanguage = selectedLanguage;`

But childSlectedLanguage still null, despite that selectedLanguage is not.

I tried also

```
  @Action(InitializeChildrenSelectedLanguage)
  initializeChildrenSelectedLanguage(
    { getState, patchState }: StateContext<LanguageSelectorStateModel>,
    {  }: InitializeChildrenSelectedLanguage
  ) {
    const state = getState();
    Object.assign(state.childSelectedLanguage, state.selectedLanguage);
    patchState(state);
  }
```

But also i can't assign the object to the content.

First question: Why I cannot assign the object?

Second question: How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: You need to create a minimal but complete example of your code, as it is not necessarily clear what the problem is with the snippets you've shown.

Comment: I edited my post, but I don't think is relevant to the problem

Comment: Where are you trying to update the childSelectedLanguage and is this really the assignment you are using? childSelectedLanguage = selectedLanguage;

Comment: I tried to do it in stead of  Object.assign(state.childSelectedLanguage, state.selectedLanguage);. yes it's real

Answer (score 0):

To create an object from an other, you can maybe use that kind of function

```
/**
 * Update attributes of Class or object.
 *
 * @param origin - Original Object
 * @param newValues - New Values
 */
export function updateFields<T>(origin: T, newValues: Partial<T>): T {
  if (typeof origin !== 'object' || typeof newValues !== 'object') {
    throw new Error('Arguments must be kind of Classe or Object');
  }

  const keys = (Object.keys(newValues) as unknown) as Array<keyof T>;
  const result = origin; // Reassignment of Function Parameters is prohibited so we do a copy.

  keys.forEach(function affectValues(key) {
    result[key] = newValues[key] as never;
  });
  return result;
}
```

In your code you can do this

```
state.selectedLanguage = updateFields<YourType>(state.selectedLanguage, selectedLanguage);
```

Comment: the function updateFields attent to have an object and not null value. I found a solution. I used @ImmutableContext() decorator